# Adding text to existing csv file's rows using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, insert, contains, import-csv

I'd like to add a the text `;12345` in a csv file to every row that contains `DE123456789` in the column `VAT Number`.

Example:

```
header1; header2; header3; header4; header5; VAT Number; header7; Kundennummer
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; DE123456789; EUR
CD; 456789; 22.24; Text; SW;
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; DE123456789; EUR
```

My desired saved file would be

```
header1; header2; header3; header4; header5; VAT Number; header7; Kundennummer
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; DE123456789; EUR; 12345
CD; 456789; 22.24; Text; SW;
AB; 12345; AB123456789; 10.03.2021; GT; DE123456789; EUR; 12345
```

My attempt was like this:

```
$File = 'S:\Test\test.csv'
$Check = (Import-Csv $File)."VAT Number" | ForEach-Object {
    if ($Check -Contains "DE123456789") {
        Select-Object @{Name='Kundennummer';Expression={'12345'}} | 
        Export-Csv $File -NoTypeInformation
    }
}
```

but there's nothing happening to the file at all.

I've found this code in a forum where a similar question has been asked. There was no feedback though.

Comment: You do know that your CSV file misses a column in the `CD` line don't you?. Also, your question is about adding a new column with no header to the file..

Comment: @Theo You're right regarding the column name. As I am preparing this file right now, I've added an additional column to the file (and edited it to the qeustion just now). The rows starting with CD are in fact shorter. They have less columns. I know it's weird - it's just how the provided files and data are. That's directly connected to my other question from 1 hour ago which is also not cleared yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since you have provided enough headers to the file, this could work for you:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheInputFile.csv' -Delimiter ';'
# get an array of the column headers
$allHeaders = $csv[0].PsObject.Properties.Name
$data = foreach ($item in $csv) {
    if ($item.'VAT Number' -eq 'DE123456789') { $item.Kundennummer = 12345 }
    # output a new object making sure all fields are present (allbeit some will remain empty)
    $item | Select-Object $allHeaders
}

$data | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\TheNewFile.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. Now there's just the split left that I mentioned in my other question.

Comment: @Nerevar.de Have a look, I just posted an answer on that one to ;)